# Local Mercurial - Remote SVN

Tags: mercurial, dvcs

I like Mercurial very much. But most of the companys I work for aren't ready to change to Mercurial, yet. So I'm wondering whether there is a convenient way to use a local Mercurial repository and commit (what I would otherwise push to my remote Mercurial repo) to the companys' svn. I would prefer a solution which can be easily integrated into my workflow as a MercurialEclipse user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [WorkingWithSubversion](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WorkingWithSubversion).

*When you want to push the changes directly into svn, you first pull the latest changes from svn, then rebase your changes to the svn HEAD and push them back.*

```
$ hg pull --svn # pull the changes from svn
$ hg up your_head # update the repo to the head of the changes you want to push to svn
$ hg rebase --svn # rebase your_head onto svn
$ hg push --svn
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [HgSubversion](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgSubversion), it should suits your needs.

You can then use Mercurial as a Subversion client.